# Is 'analytic' opposed to 'synthesis', as universal rather than traditional?

Tags: aesthetics, art, analytic-synthetic-divide

I'm reading a book on Russian theatre and it mentions

> a similarity in intent... [to]
> the work of the cubists... intention was both analytic and
> synthetic... both the investigation of the universal ideas... and
> bringing together of elements that have defined that practice across
> the scope of theatre history

Is this analytic/synthetic division in aesthetics the same as it is in anyone's philosophy? Is this how the terms are implicitly used in cubism?

> Synthetic cubism began when the artists started adding textures and patterns to their paintings, experimenting with collage using newspaper print and patterned paper. Analytical cubism was about breaking down an object (like a bottle) viewpoint-by-viewpoint, into a fragmentary image; whereas synthetic cubism was about flattening out the image and sweeping away the last traces of allusion to three-dimensional space.

According to wikipedia, this - by Picasso - is synthetic cubism

[image]

And the Tate lists this - by Braque - as analytic

[image]

Just wondering if these loose trends carry the meaning above in the quote, and how that quote might link to philosophy.

Comment: "*Eternity is in love with the productions of time.*"

Comment: ahh william blake.

Comment: Very very loose connection. The origin is probably only semantical: dividing Vs collecting.

Comment: yeah i think you are right @MauroALLEGRANZA just verbal play